# Issue with converting NSString * to String and passing Character as parameter in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring

I am calling a Objective method from Swift by using a Bridging header.

```
-(NSString *) PatternSetCreator: (char)Signature detection_time_in_sec:(int)detection_time_in_sec patternLength:(int)patternLength maxPatternSetSize:(int)maxPatternSetSize
```

There are two issuse:

a) I am not able to pass a single character as parameter while calling this method from Swift

b) I am not exactly sure how to get the return type NSString and assign it to a String variable

Comment: Although I am new to Objective C and Swift but I think that will be writing C style code in Objective C. Hopefully there will be a way to call this as it is.

Answer (score 2):

A single C `char` in Swift is represented as `CChar`, a typealias for `Int8`.

(similarly, C `int` in Swift is `CInt`, a typealias for `Int32`)

If you want a specific character and are using Swift 1.2, there’s an initializer for `UInt8` that takes a `UnicodeScalar`.  Annoyingly, though, you have to then convert it to a `Int8` to make it compatible with the C method:

```
    let ch = CChar(UInt8(ascii: "x"))
    let i = CInt(100)
    let s = obj.PatternSetCreator(ch, 
                   detection_time_in_sec: i, 
                   patternLength: i, 
                   maxPatternSetSize: i)
```

You should not need to do anything special to turn the returned `NSString` to a `String`.  The bridging will do that automatically.

(or rather, it’ll return a `String!` – but if the objective c code is guaranteed to return a valid string every time and never a null pointer, the definition can be changed to `-(nonnull NSString *) PatternSetCreator: etc…` which means it will return a `String` instead)